# Where should my class code go and is it referenced properly?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, wpf-controls

I'm following this: [WPF WebBrowser Control Custom Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455645/wpf-webbrowser-control-custom-property)

I get the same error as the user *The property 'Html' was not found in type 'WebBrowser'.*

I've done as the user who gave the answer suggested and changed namespace, but the error persists, the only thing I can think of is how I've added the class... I right clicked on my project in the solution explorer and added a class document then within it created copied the code.

Any ideas? I know it's something dumb ass on my part.

Some screenshots and code of what I've done, it's a new temp project to test so I can rule anything else out:

[image]
BrowserHtmlBinding.vb

```
Public Class BrowserHtmlBinding

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared BindableSourceProperty As DependencyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Html",
                                            GetType(String),
                                            GetType(WebBrowser),
                                            New UIPropertyMetadata(Nothing,
                                                                    AddressOf BindableSourcePropertyChanged))

    Public Shared Function GetBindableSource(obj As DependencyObject) As String
        Return DirectCast(obj.GetValue(BindableSourceProperty), String)
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub SetBindableSource(obj As DependencyObject, value As String)
        obj.SetValue(BindableSourceProperty, value)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub BindableSourcePropertyChanged(o As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        Dim webBrowser = DirectCast(o, System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser)
        webBrowser.NavigateToString(DirectCast(e.NewValue, String))
    End Sub

End Class
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2" 
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser custom:Html="&lt;b&gt;Hey Now&lt;/b&gt;" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

EDIT: As Mark pointed out I was missing some text on the 'webbrowser' control, which I've updated and has generate more errors, but including the original one.

[image]

Comment: The answer to the referenced question has the following in the XAML: `<WebBrowser custom:BrowserHtmlBinding.Html="&lt;b&gt;Hey Now&lt;/b&gt;" />` - you seem to be missing the 'BrowserHtmlBinding.' part.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that @Mark, I've updated my post with the errors now generated after updating the code - it has generate more errors, but including the original one.

Comment: In your first screenshot, you seem to have the `BrowserHtmlBinding` class nested in another class with the same name.

Comment: Also, I would think that the attached property is really named `BindableSource`, so perhaps `<WebBrowser custom:BrowserHtmlBinding.BrowserHtmlBinding.BindableSource="&lt;b&gt;Hey Now&lt;/b&gt;" />` - however, I would un-nest the class.  The first parameter to `RegisterAttached` should probably also be `"BindableSource"`.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to change the screenshot after I altered it, it's just in one class. I've changed BindableSource and tried the new control... It says, among other things: *Nested types are not supported: BrowserHtmlBinding.BrowserHtmlBinding.*

Comment: When I change to: *<WebBrowser custom:BrowserHtmlBinding.BindableSource="&lt;b&gt;Hey Now&lt;/b&gt;" />* It says *The property 'Html' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:WpfApplication2'* And *The name "BrowserHtmlBinding" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"*

Comment: Have you verified that the root namespace for the project is actually `WpfApplication2` - project properties, application tab?  Also that you don't have any `Namespace` statements around your class definition?

Comment: Yep, its WpfApplication2, no Namespace statements anywhere.

Comment: If I do *custom:BrowserHtmlBinding* then the dot *custom:BrowserHtmlBinding.* intelisense brings up *BindableSource* to make the full path - which to me says it's all joined up correctly, but still have those errors. Really confused.

Comment: Odd, and unfortunately it works for me.  Maybe try a clean and rebuild, and close and reopen any editor windows in VS - sometimes it doesn't seem to clear out errors correctly.

Comment: Could you zip your project and mail please? Thepurpledongle@gmail.com would really appreciate it.

Comment: Unfortunately not from work, but I can send from home this evening.

Comment: No need to send the file now @Mark - I've just moved the code etc to my main application and all errors have gone - it's fine, thanks for your help. I'm not 100% on what actually fixed it in the end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF WebBrowser Control Custom Property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455645/wpf-webbrowser-control-custom-property)

Comment: Gmail blocked my email anyway, because of the attachment.  I've flagged this as dupe, since it's not recreatable and matches your linked question - not sure if you can just delete the question to clean things up.

Comment: Yeah, no probs - And thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to be declaring an `Attached Property`, but you have *not* done that correctly. If you look at the [`DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597495(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll see that the second `Type` parameter is named `ownerType`. This is *not* the `Type` of the control that you are writing an `Attached Property` for, but the `Type` of the actual class that defines the property. In your case, that would be `BrowserHtmlBinding`.

Disclaimer: You *may* have other errors too.

---

UPDATE >>>

Ok, I see more problems in your screenshot. You have somehow managed to define a class within a class and that is wrong. Also you have no Namespace for your class... another mistake. To remedy this, please change this:

```
Public Class BrowserHtmlBinding
    Public Class BrowserHtmlBinding
        ...
    End Class
End Class
```

To this:

```
Namespace WpfApplication2
    Public Class BrowserHtmlBinding
        ...
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Now the `BrowserHtmlBinding` class *will* be in the `WpfApplication2` Namespace.

Finally, if you still have problems, please read the Custom Attached Properties section of the [Attached Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx#custom) page on MSDN to ensure that you have declared your `Attached Property` correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to this, but still get the same 3 errors... Public Shared BindableSourceProperty As DependencyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Html",
                                            GetType(String),
                                            GetType(BrowserHtmlBinding),
                                            New UIPropertyMetadata(Nothing,
                                                                    AddressOf BindableSourcePropertyChanged))

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned to @Mark that I realised the class shouldn't be in the class and changed it. I've added the Namespace tags as you suggested but it still can't see it. `Attached Property` looks ok as far as I can tell - Do you have a working copy your side that you could send to me please? @Mark is sending one too, but another can't hurt I guess. thepurpledongle@gmail.com

Comment: Cancel that it's working! Well kinda... I was playing with the property deleting the commas and putting them back in to bring up the helper, then I noticed the errors change, there is still an error on this line `<WebBrowser custom:BrowserHtmlBinding.BindableSource="&lt;b&gt;Hey Now&lt;/b&gt;" />` which is this `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` but if I hit F5 it works, be good to determine what the error is and a fix.

Comment: oh, `Namespace WpfApplication2` in or not in makes no difference.

Comment: Again, cancel that - I've just moved the code etc to my main application and all errors have gone - it's fine, thanks for your help.